# How to evenly stretch nav items ul li to the width of a container

Tags: html, css

I have a simple menu place in a container which has width as 100% but ul width is set to `max-width: 1100px;` leaving space on right side from the last element of menu.

How can i evenly stretch menu to the width of the container.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqOGLL

```css
.container{ width:100%; background-color: #f00;}
.mm-nav-wrap {
 max-width: 1100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height:35px;
}
.mm-main-nav {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: 400;
 background-color: green;
 height:35px;
}
ul, ol {
 padding: 0px;
}
ol, ul {
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.mm-main-nav li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 line-height: normal;
}
.mm-main-nav li a {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 600;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 13px 1px 13px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #111;
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="mm-nav-wrap">
            <ul class="mm-group mm-main-nav">
                <li> <a href="#" class="mm-nav-item"> HOME  </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="mm-nav-item"> ABOUT US  </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="mm-nav-item"> MENU ONE  </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="mm-nav-item"> MENU TWO  </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="mm-nav-item"> MENU THREE  </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="mm-nav-item"> FOUR  </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="mm-nav-item"> MENUFIVE  </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="mm-nav-item"> SIX  </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="mm-nav-item"> SEVEN  </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="mm-nav-item"> CONTACT US  </a> </li>
            </ul>
   </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Let me check this example, i had tried earlier this one https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/make-li-fit-ul/ but didnt not work

Comment: I solved the issue as i had and extra class which was creating problem in actual code `.mm-group::after {
 content: '.';
 visibility: hidden;
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 line-height: 0px;
}` removed it and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you require in your design with `display: table` and `display:table-cell` properties. Try this code.

```
.mm-main-nav {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.mm-main-nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

However, if you don't need all the menu items to be equal width, you can remove `table-layout: fixed;`

Comment: There is no need to use `display: table` when you can use `flex`...

Comment: It is working on the codepen when i use the example. But in my code it is working but not fitting to the container with.